# SQL Server LAST like functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called MyTable in Sql Server that looks like this:

```
Name | Value | Date
A      V1      01.01.2012
A      V2      02.02.2012
B      V1      02.02.2012
B      V2      01.01.2012
```

Now I would like to query the table and group results by the Name. However, for each name I need to take the latest value. Sample query result:

```
Name | Value | Date
A      V2      02.02.2012
B      V1      02.02.2012
```

What's the simplest query to achieve that?

Comment: have you tried max()?

Comment: from what I understand max will always return V2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query which gonna work probably on any database:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM MyTable a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b
 ON b.Name = a.Name
 AND b.Date > a.Date
WHERE b.Value is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
;WITH abc AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS rn
   FROM tmp
)
SELECT *
FROM abc
WHERE rn = 1
```

Hope this will help you!

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: can you pls add some comment, it's not clear to me what you are doing here. thanks

Comment: Above query will return you result top 1 row from most recent date, you will get same output which you are expecting, try with your sample data. Thanks Suresh